# Whom to request debug analysis assistance from Microsoft?

Tags: analysis, dump, debug, subscription

I believe our organization has a MSDN subscription from Microsoft.  While scouring the Internet for information to assist with crash dump analysis I noticed a post stating that there is some limited assistance available to MSDN subscription holders for debug analysis assistance.

I request to know if that's true and how to initialize the assistance request.

Comment: Contact Microsoft, they'll provide the only legitimate answer for you.

Comment: My bad for the incorrect StackExchange site.  What site does this fall under?

Comment: MSDN subscriptions are per-developer, not per-organization. You should know *for sure* that you personally have a subscription paid for by your employer, if you indeed have one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSDN subscribers get [up to four technical support tickets per subscription year](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/bb266240.aspx). Without a solid reference to what you are referring to, this is likely the support that you read about. Open a ticket up with Microsoft, tell them your problem, and submit your dump file. They're usually very thorough in their ticket resolution.